# Direct new desktop files to certain monitor

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop, multi-monitor

Is there a way in Linux Mint to designate which monitor new files on the Desktop will be shown on? I have two monitors, and I'd prefer to have them appear on the right monitor since I keep the left mostly covered with open windows.

I came across [a similar question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/84115/ubuntu-twinview-i-want-the-desktop-icons-on-the-right-monitor) but there wasn't a satisfactory answer.